# About the word "RELATED"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

When we say "car-related" industries, does it refer to only the "peripheral" industries like petroleum/maintenance/OEM/distributorship industries that have a relationship with cars, or does it refer to both the car industry itself as well as the peripheral industries?

In other words, let's say if I want to refer to both the car industry and its peripheral industries in my speech, should I say "the car industry and its related industries", or should I just say "car-related industries"?

I'm having trouble identifying the range of coverage that the word "RELATED" implies.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky one. In my opinion, "car-related industries" refers only to the "peripheral" industries you describe, and *not necessarily* the car industry itself. My best guess at why...while the "car industry" *theoretically* encompasses all peripheral industries, in practice it's used to refer only to the primary manufacture(rs) of cars (Ford, Toyota, Volkswagen, etc.). Therefore, we need something to describe these similar-but-not-quite-equal industries: "car-related."